# sed variable expansion issues

Tags: sed, variable

So I have made some progress on the bash script I'm writing but can't seem to figure out how to write the following so that it expands the variables. I tried the normal ${variable} and the \$(variable) as well as some other random helpless attempts.

I even tried using eval wrapping it in " " but it still didn't work (unless ran from command line but wouldn't work in the bash script).

```
sed -i 's/.*output_snat_lo.conf:/    - '\''\\-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/32 -d $DNAT -j SNAT --to-source $SINT'\''\n&/' file.yaml
```

Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: Stuff inside single quotes is not subject to dollar expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `$DNAT` inside the single quotes to `'"$DNAT"'` to terminate the single quotes, start double quoting (as you almost always want variable expansion to take place inside double quotes to stop word splitting), put in the variable, terminate the double quotes and restart the single quotes.

```
sed -i 's|.*output_snat_lo.conf:|    - '\''\\-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/32 -d '"$DNAT"' -j SNAT --to-source '"$SINT"\''\n&|' file.yaml
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
~]$ sed -i 's/.*output_snat_lo.conf:/    - '\''\\-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/32 -d '"$DNAT"' -j SNAT --to-source '"$SINT"\''\n&/' file.yaml

sed: -e expression #1, char 72: unknown option to `s'

~]$

Comment: Edited to change sed delimiter to | as / is in the replacement text

Answer (score 0):

If the string expansion contains a path separator (i.e `/`) you must use another character (that's not in the pattern).

Also note that when using $variables, use double quotes e.g:

```
sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/' $some_file
```

becomes

```
sed -i "s|$old_string|$new_string|" $some_file
```